# Robolectric: class file for org.robolectric.util.ShadowProvider not found

Tags: android, robolectric

I just downloaded the Robolectric samples and tried to build it, but I'm getting an error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples.git
```

(Edited settings.gradle to remove the api-16 and api-19 samples, so I'm only building android-api-21.)

Now when I do `gradle test` it fails at task ':android-api-21:compileTestDebugJava':

```
:android-api-21:compileTestDebugJava
/tmp/robolectric-samples/android-api-21/src/test/java/com/example/activity/MainActivityTest.java:14: error: cannot access ShadowProvider
import static org.robolectric.Shadows.shadowOf;
^
  class file for org.robolectric.util.ShadowProvider not found
/tmp/robolectric-samples/android-api-21/src/test/java/com/example/activity/MainActivityTest.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    final Menu menu = shadowOf(activity).getOptionsMenu();
                      ^
  symbol:   method shadowOf(Activity)
  location: class MainActivityTest
2 errors
:android-api-21:compileTestDebugJava FAILED
```

I guess it's possible that it's just a temporary problem with the 3.0-SNAPSHOT build or am I doing something wrong?

Some more info:

- OS X Yosemite
- I have the latest Android SDK 21 and build tools 21.1.2 installed
- I deleted my ~/.m2 and ~/.gradle/caches directories first
- ran `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies test`

Comment: The exact version of the robolectric jar that was downloaded is: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/robolectric/robolectric/3.0-SNAPSHOT/robolectric-3.0-20150116.190205-104.jar

Comment: Tried again today and it's working now. It was just a temporary problem -  issues with their Travis build publishing snapshots to Sonatype.